AirTable Error: Exceeded quota of 30 table queries per script invocation
I have an extension setup in my base with AirTable and Plumsail. My goal is to trigger the automation once my line item is approved in the interface. If I manually run the extension, it works and populates my PDF. However, when the automation is triggered with the conditions it will not run to completion - it gives Error: Exceeded quota of 30 table queries per script invocation.
const config = input.config();
const rootTable = base.getTable('PO Header');
const processStartUrl = 'https://api.plumsail.com/api/v2/processes/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyy/start';
const recordId = config.RecordId;
const tokens = [
  'PODate',
  'PONumber',
  'AppLV1Date',
  'AppLV2Date',
  'Supplier',
  'Supplier.SupplierName',
  'Supplier.Address1',
  'Supplier.City',
  'Supplier.Zip',
  'Supplier.EmailAddress',
  'Supplier.PhoneNumber',
  'Supplier.State',
  'Supplier.State.name',
  'ShipTo',
  'ShipTo.Phone',
  'POLines',
  'POLines.LineDescription',
  'POLines.POUnits',
  'POLines.POUnitCost',
  'ApproverLevel1',
  'ApproverLevel1.Name',
  'ApproverLevel2',
  'ApproverLevel2.Name'
];

const payload = await getPayload(recordId, rootTable, tokens);
const response = await fetch(processStartUrl,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });

const responseJson = await response.json();

await tryAttachResult(responseJson, recordId, 'fld4v4XlcWwZfaXas', rootTable);
output.set('documentLink', responseJson.link);

async function getPayload(recordId, table, tags) {
  const simpleTags = [...new Set(tags.reduce((acc, token) => {
    token.split('.').forEach((simpeToken) => {
        acc.push(simpeToken);
    });
    return acc;
  }, []))];

  const selectedFields = table.fields.filter((field) => simpleTags.includes(formatTokenName(field.name.replace(/\./g, ''))));
  const record = await table.selectRecordAsync(recordId, {fields: selectedFields});
  if (record) {
    const recordValues = await getRecordValues(selectedFields, record, [table.id], simpleTags);
    const payload = filtredTokens(recordValues, tags);
    return payload;
  }
  return {};
}

async function getRecordValues(fields, record, linkedTables, tags) {
  const reservedNames = [];
  return fields.reduce(async (acc, field) => {
    const accumulator = await acc;

    const fieldNamesList = fields.reduce((acc, currentField) => {
      if (currentField.name === field.name) return acc;
      const name = formatTokenName(currentField.name.replace(/\./g, ''));
      acc.push(name);
      return acc;
    }, []);

    fieldNamesList.push(...reservedNames);

    const formatName = formatTokenName(field.name.replace(/\./g, ''));
    let fieldName;

    if (field.name.toLowerCase() === formatName.toLowerCase()) {
      fieldName = formatName;
    } else {
      fieldName = getUniqueName(fieldNamesList, formatName);
      reservedNames.push(fieldName);
    }

    if (field.type === 'multipleRecordLinks') {
        const tableId = field.options.linkedTableId;
        const singleRecordLink = field.options.prefersSingleRecordLink;

        const table = base.getTable(tableId);
        if (linkedTables.includes(tableId) || !table) {
            const recordValue = record.getCellValue(field);
            if (singleRecordLink) {
                accumulator[fieldName] = recordValue[0].name;
            } else {
                accumulator[fieldName] = recordValue;
            }
            return accumulator;
        }

        const selectedFields = table.fields;
        const linkedRecordsIds = (record?.getCellValue(field.name) || []).map(({id}) => id);
        const linkedQuery = await table.selectRecordsAsync({fields: selectedFields, recordIds: linkedRecordsIds});
        const records = linkedQuery.records;
        const values = await Promise.all(records.map(async (record) => {
            return await getRecordValues(selectedFields, record, linkedTables.concat(tableId), tags);
        }))

        if (singleRecordLink) {
            accumulator[fieldName] = {};
            if (values?.length) {
                Object.entries(values[0]).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                    accumulator[fieldName][key] = value;
                })
            }
        } else {
            accumulator[fieldName] = values;
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

    if (field.type === 'multipleLookupValues') {
        const recordValues = record.getCellValue(field);
        if (Array.isArray(recordValues)) {
            const values = recordValues.map((value) => {
                // for barcode
                if (value && Object.keys(value).length === 1 && value.text) {
                    return { value: value.text }
                }
                return { value };
            });
            accumulator[fieldName] = values;
        } else {
            accumulator[fieldName] = recordValues;
        }
        return accumulator;
    }

    if (field.type === 'barcode') {
        accumulator[fieldName] = record.getCellValueAsString(field);
        return accumulator
    }

    if (field.type === 'checkbox') {
        accumulator[fieldName] = record.getCellValue(field) || false;
        return  accumulator;
    }
    accumulator[fieldName] = record.getCellValue(field);
    return  accumulator;
  }, Promise.resolve({}));
}

function filtredTokens(tree, pattern, prefix = null) {
    return Object.keys(tree).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const nextPrefix = prefix ? String(prefix) + '.' + String(key) : key;
        if (!pattern.includes(prefix ? String(prefix) + '.' + String(key) : key)) {
            return acc;
        }
        if (Array.isArray(tree[key])) {
            const newValue = tree[key].map((item) => filtredTokens(item, pattern, nextPrefix));
            acc[key] = newValue;
            return acc;
        }
        if (tree[key] && typeof tree[key] === 'object') {
            const newValue = filtredTokens(tree[key], pattern, nextPrefix);
            acc[key] = newValue;
            return acc;
        }
        acc[key] = tree[key];
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

function formatTokenName (name) {
  return name.split(' ')
    .map((word) => {
        const withoutSymbols = word.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9.]/g, '');
        if (!withoutSymbols) return '';
        return withoutSymbols[0].toUpperCase() + withoutSymbols.slice(1)
    }).join('')
    .split('.').map((word) => {
        if (!word) return '';
        return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }).join('.');
}

function getUniqueName (namesList, name, num= 1) {
  if (!namesList.length || !namesList.includes(name)) return name;
  const alternateName = String(name) + String(num);

  if (!namesList.includes(alternateName)) return alternateName;

  const newNum = num + 1;
  return getUniqueName(namesList, name, newNum);
}

async function tryAttachResult(data, recordId, field, table) {
    try {
      const record = await table.selectRecordAsync(recordId, { fields: [field] });
      const url = new URL(decodeURI(data.link));
      const filename = url?.searchParams?.get('rscd')?.split(';')
        ?.find((element) => element.startsWith('filename'))?.split('"')[1];

        const cellValue = record.getCellValue(field);
        table.updateRecordAsync(record, {
          [field]: [
              ...(cellValue || []).filter((value) => value?.filename !== filename),
              { url: data?.link, ...(filename && { filename } ) }
          ]
        });
    } catch {
      console.log('Failed to attach file');
    }
  }

